# Reflecting an older version of System.dll

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, uri

I have a build activity that reflects one of our libraries to compare it against a domain definition.  During the reflection, whenever I try to reflect Uri it returns as RunTimePropertyInfo instead of Uri and whenever I check any of the reflected properties I get an exception stating ...

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=2.0.5.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=7cec85d7bea7798e, retargetable=yes"
```

The build activity is compiled with System.dll version 4.0.0.0.  I suspect this is the issue.  Is there a way for me to reflect a type on an older version of System.dll.

So far this has only failed with Uri.  Any ideas?

Comment: I tried repointing my build action to the same system.dll but that had no affect.

Worth noting that the version of System.dll that the library I am reflecting is from the .net 4 portable library.

Comment: You are mixing framework targets, that never works out well.  2.0.5.0 is a Silverlight version number.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is versioning problem,if you are using diffrent version of dll that is used in project in that case such error can take place.

here is one simple solution that worked for me in past,it will work for you if there is same problem.
you can use "**bindingRedirect**" tag in web.config by defining old and new version of problematic dll. so that means it will ignore old version of dll reference and use newer one if found.and will not generate error.

here is the reference link.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion but it didn't help.  I guess what I need it to do is pick up the old dll when reflecting not the new one.

Comment: Can you copy your code here what you have written in web.config ? it must work if problem is related to version only

Comment: It might not only be associated to version.  This only occurs on one data type 'Uri'. I'm just going to place a item in my log for this and skip it when it occurs.  It will satisfy our needs.  Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like IKVM.Reflection,

http://weblog.ikvm.net/PermaLink.aspx?guid=d0dc2476-471b-45f3-96bf-a90bc2f5800b

Microsoft's reflection is tied to the hosted .NET Framework, so you cannot load an older version of the core libraries as wished.